# Using StretchDIBits to copy PNG (with alpha)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Could someone help me? 
How I can copy png to virtual HDC. 
Transparent pixels are always black.
I tried but alpha is always black. 
Seems like BITMAPINFOHEADER does not support alpha.
Thank you very much.
and sorry for my English. Peace.
(Note I need to use GDI only)

```
// fill background
HBRUSH hbrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(color.red(), color.green(), color.blue()));
::FillRect(m_virtualHDC, &wRect, hbrush);
DeleteObject(hbrush);
// load image
QImage pix;
pix.load("D:\\1.png");
// draw image with alpha
BITMAPINFO bmInfo;
ZeroMemory(&bmInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
BITMAPINFOHEADER& BMPInfoHeader = bmInfo.bmiHeader;
BMPInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
BMPInfoHeader.biWidth = pix.width();
BMPInfoHeader.biHeight = pix.height();
BMPInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
BMPInfoHeader.biBitCount = 32;
BMPInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
BMPInfoHeader.biSizeImage = pix.byteCount();
BMPInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
BMPInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
BMPInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
SetStretchBltMode(m_virtualHDC, HALFTONE);
StretchDIBits(m_virtualHDC,
    targetRect.x(), targetRect.y(), targetRect.width(), targetRect.height(),
    sourceRect.x(), sourceRect.y(), sourceRect.width(), sourceRect.height(),
    pix.bits(), &bmInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

Answer (score 3):

GDI in general does not support an alpha channel.

You need to use an API that has dedicated alpha support, e. g. [`AlphaBlend()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend) or [GDI+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-gdi-start).

Most of these APIs have very poor resampling quality. I suggest to use a third-party library like [stb_image_resize](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_resize.h) to resample in memory and use APIs like `AlphaBlend()` only to display the final result to the screen, without doing further scaling.

Comment: Hello, already tried to use AlphaBlend(), but seems like it changes the alpha channel for all pixels.

Comment: @Ruslan Make sure to use [premultiplied alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24596832/7571258), otherwise you will get wrong results. PNG is not premultiplied by default.